# search result in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a help as I have tried several options but not succeed recently. The main issue is that the header of the result table is always shown even the result has a value "no result" and I simply want only that the message "no result" appears without the header of the table.

```
if (preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['search'])) {     
    $name=$_POST['search']; 

    $sql="SELECT airport_id, airport_name, region_name, airport_code, island_name FROM airport, region, island WHERE airport_name LIKE '" . $name . "%' AND region_id=airport_region AND island_id=airport_island";   

    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
    $n=0;

    //* here is the table header with echo //should not be visible when $n=0
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
        $id_airport=$row['airport_id'];
        extract($row); 

        //*result of table when $n>=0 with the header of the table//
        ++$n;
    }

    if (0 == $n) {
        echo " no result ";
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I'm going to say, you're probably not showing us all the code in question

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    //there are results
    //echo tale header
    //also start while loop
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  



$id_airport=$row['airport_id'];

extract($row); 



}
}else{
 echo 'No result';
}
```

Comment: yes i see now that mysql_num_rows was the solution :)  fixed thank you for your effort